# How to stop python imported from running first and only run when called in code

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I am currently importing a python script in to my main python file. When i import the script and run the main script via the command line , the imported scripts seems to be running first and displaying output and then my main script runs after that. I have no main() in my imported script and only have this in my main script. My code is as follows :

```
import argparse
from test_compare_filesets import testing


def main():


 print("export_data is the main file")


 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 parser.add_argument("-d", "--export-date", action="store_true", required=False)
 parser.add_argument("-t", "--execute-test", action="store_true", required=False)

 args = parser.parse_args()

 if args.execute_test :
     print "Test Mode"
     testing()

 if args.export_date :
     print "Normal Mode"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
else:

    print ("DIE EXPORT_DATA")
```

Comment: Its the function compare_filsets which returns values first when the script is imported.

Comment: That isn't possible. In fact none of your code does anything at all, as you never even call the `testing` function. (Although note, there's nothing at all special about `main()` in Python.)

Comment: I do. Please look at my code again @DanielRoseman

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @juniorpydev, instead of posting the same code with the same question over and over again, please post a **proper** MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `from test_compare_filesets import testing` in your main file, the module `test_compare_filesets.py` is run.
When the functions are defined and then the last part is run:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    testing()
else:
    print "DIE COMPARE FILSETS"
```

Since this module is being imported, it's `__name__` attribute is **not** `"__main__"`, therefore the `else` clause is run, printing `DIE COMPARE FILSETS`. After that import, your main script defines its own functions.
Since your main script has `__name__` as `"__main__"`, it then runs the `main()` function and will print `export_data is the main file`.
Therefore, you would expect the following output:

```
$ python main_script.py
DIE COMPARE FILSETS
export_data is the main file
```

(followed by whatever prints during the `main()` function.

Comment: right i understand. what i want to do is , when i run python main_script.py -t and pass it the t flag , this runs all me tests and prints out the output to the terminal. If you look at my code below , i have tried to run this but it seems to fail with RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: As other have written, please provide a MCVE and the error trace back that you are getting so we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

so far this is my code. Essentially when running the python script with the -t flag this will return everything from test_compare_filesets and print to the terminal , where as if -d flag is passed it will simply print "Normal Mode". I seem to be getting a RunTimeError with this issue saying "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object:

```
import argparse
from test_compare_filesets import testing

def main():



    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--export-date", action="store_true", required=False)
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--execute-test", action="store_true", required=False)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.execute_test :
        print "Test Mode"
        testing()

    else:
        print "Normal Mode"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
else:

    print ("DIE EXPORT_DATA")
```

Comment: This should be an update to the question. But your else statement does not do anything other than print "Normal Mode". What else are you expecting it to do? (And if you get an error, you should post the whole traceback, again as an update to the question.)